# Configure shadow plugin to build a fat jar of only dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

Is it possible to configure the shadow plugin to build an uber jar with only the dependencies of a project?
Ideally I would like to run

```
./gradlew shadowJar
```

and have it produce two jars within my *build/libs/* folder -

1) A slim jar with just the project class files/resources

2) A fat jar with all the project dependencies included

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Disabling the `application` plugin from my project did the trick for me.